# Probability question: P(X < Y), X and Y are uniform with different domains

Tags: probability

If I have a random variable X that is uniform on [0, 0.5] and another random variable Y that is uniform on [0.25, 0.75], what is the probability that X is smaller than Y? How does one solve this?

Comment: It's at least $1/2$, can you see why?

Comment: Yes, I figured that since half of the mass of X is between 0 and 0.25.

Comment: Can you continue along those lines?

Comment: Well, the other half of X is between 0.25 and 0.5 while Y has 50% of its mass in that same interval. I thought that within this interval [0.25, 0.5] X < Y half of the time which would give P(X < Y) = 0.5 + 0.25 = 0.75

Comment: Alright, you're missing a little bit more. If $X$ is in $[.25,.5]$ and $Y$ is in the same, what is the probability that $X<Y$?

Comment: I figure that the joint density is 4, but when I integrate this over x between 0.25 and y, and over y between 0.25 and 0.5, I get a negative number which is obviously wrong.

Comment: If $X,Y$ are uniformly distributed on $[.25,.5]$, you don't need any integrals. Use symmetry.

Comment: I thought symmetry implied a result of 0.5. So is the solution: 1 x 0.5 + 0.5 x 0.5 = 0.75 ? I guess not because I already suggested this. Is it: 1 x 0.5 + 0.5 x 0.5 x 0.5 = 0.6125 ?

Comment: You have to add three terms.

Comment: Why? Thanassis in his answer below specified three terms but the third term, namely P( X < Y given Y > 0.5) is zero. Okay, I get it: I have to use the law of total probability. But 0.6125 is my best answer now.

Comment: .6125 is incorrect. :)

Comment: But why? I appreciate any help you can give.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1979358/

Answer (score 2):

You must add three probabilities.

First, $P(X\leq .25)=\frac12$. Then $P(Y\geq .5)$ but we want to avoid double counting, so we want to add $P(X\geq .25)P(Y\geq .5)=\frac14$. Then given that both $X$ and $Y$ are in $[.25,.5]$, by symmetry $P(X<Y|.25<X,Y<.5)=\frac12$, so total probability is:

$$\frac12+\frac14+\frac18=\frac78$$

Another way to see this is $P(X>Y)=\frac14P(X>Y|X>.25, Y<.5)=\frac18$ so $P(X<Y)=1-\frac18=\frac78$.

Comment: Thanks a lot Zachary. I get it now.

Answer (score 1):

You can start breaking it in cases and assign appopriate probabilities in each case.

- If $X<0.25$ then $X$ is certainly smaller than $Y$
- If $Y>0.5$ then $X$ is certainly smaller than $Y$.
- If $X \ge 0.25$ and $Y \le 0.5$ then what can you say about $X$ being smaller than $Y$?

What is the probability for each of these cases? Also be aware of double counting. If you want to avoid double counting you can make the cases strictly distinct/disjoint: First one as is, second one $X \ge 0.25$ and $Y >0.5$, third one as is.

Can you find the final answer? Have a try first and then  I'll edit my answer to be complete.